# How to structure Helm chart with different environments?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I plan to use Helm for deploying purposes. I have three applications/pods p1,p2,p3 and each of these has 2 enivronments dev, prod and in each environment there is a configmap.yml and deployment.yml.

I plan on using helm, however how can I structure these. Do I need three helm charts?, one per application or is it possible to pack everything in one helm, considering the constraints.

I thought of the following structure.

```
+-- charts
|   \-- my-chart
|       +-- Chart.yaml        # Helm chart metadata
|       +-- templates
        |   \-- p1
             +-- configmap1.yml
             +-- dep1.yaml
............................ similiary for p2,p3

|       +-- values.yaml       # default values
|       +-- values.dev.p1.yaml   # development override values
|       +-- values.dev.p2.yaml 
|       +-- values.dev.p3.yaml  
|       +-- values.prod.p1.yaml   # production override values
|       +-- values.prod.p2.yaml  
|       +-- values.prod.p3.yaml
```

Now if I want to deploy p1 in prod , then I simply

```
helm install -f values.prod.p1.yaml helm-app
```

Would this work is this the general convention?

Comment: Typically, the value overrides are not in the chart repo. Apart from that, you are right. You pick the overrides based on the environment to deploy in. I mean thats the whole point of using helm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the single helm chart to manage all the deployment and config map.

Create the **tpl** for deployment and service so this single tpl (template) will use to generate the multiple deployment YAML configs.

So you will get the 3 YAML deployment file as output while you will be managing a single template file.

For configmap also you can follow same and keep in single helm chart is it's working fine for you.

For different environment you can mange the different **values** into **values.yaml** file like **dev-values.yaml** & **prod-values.yaml**

```
helm install -f values.prod.p1.yaml helm-app
```